# Redirect by typing only for certain urls (nginx + Angular)

Tags: angular, nginx

Im my Angular application I have the above nginx file.

```
server {
  listen 4200;
  server_tokens off;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  port_in_redirect off;

  location / {
    return 301 /vehicle;
  }

  location /vehicle {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    sub_filter 'src="/'     'src="/vehicle/';
    sub_filter 'href="/'    'href="/vehicle/';
    sub_filter 'url(/'      'url(/vehicle/';
    sub_filter '"/assets' '"/vehicle/assets';
    sub_filter '"/api' '"/vehicle/api';
    sub_filter '"/auth' '"/vehicle/auth';
    sub_filter_types text/css application/javascript image/x-icon application/json;
    sub_filter_once off;
  }

  location /vehicle/api {
    rewrite /vehicle/api/(.*) /vehicle-service/api/v1/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://vehicle-backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    client_max_body_size 15m;
  }

  location /vehicle/app {
    rewrite /vehicle/app/(.*) /aplicativo-service/api/v1/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://aplicativo-backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass_header Authorization;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

}
```

Typing any `url` into the browser bar reloads the page and takes to /vehicle. However, there is a public url (`consultation-public/consultation-request`) that I would like to be accessible by typing.

Is there any way to make this configuration?

Answer (score -1):

This behavior is defined in `location /`.
Modify this location as you need.